# ms mvc css - the div in view overlaying the parent div

Tags: css, model-view-controller

I have some css issue which I don't understand.
I have created default mvc project in ms visual studio. When I want to insert table without css formating to a view lets say default.aspx everithing its ok (it fits in the parent div), but when I try to set the table with css, something is wrong.

image: http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/3103/screenshot20120220at224.png

css file :

```
#lefttable
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }

#righttable
{
    float:right;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

I know it is possible to create another master page, or set the formatting in current site master but there must be some way to format each view like you want. Have you any advices?

If you need some more info for better analysis, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the "problem" you are referring to is that the table overflows into the blue area, and the white area doesn't expand.  If that's not the problem, then you need to explain exactly what you expect it to look like.

Assuming that's the problem, this is how floats work.  I would make one of the tables not float, or at worst you could add a div after the tables with the css `clear: both;` style.

Comment: Thanks,yes i want to white area expant over the table,clear:both; works.